# Getting value from list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

With the help of you guys, I've come up with this code that loads a database from a .txt file and fills a list with the values. I'm having a bit of trouble actually using the list to get the values though. Heres the code in my Program.cs

```
static class Program
{

    var customers = new List<Customer>();

    static void loadData() //Load data from Database
    {
        string[] stringArray = File.ReadAllLines("Name.txt");
        int lines = stringArray.Length;
        if (!((lines % 25) == 0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Corrupt Database!!! Number of lines not multiple of 25!");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<(lines/25);i++){
            customers.Add(new Customer
            {
                ID=stringArray[(i*25)],
                Name = stringArray[(i * 25) + 1],
                Address = stringArray[(i * 25) + 2],
                Phone = stringArray[(i * 25) + 3],
                Cell = stringArray[(i * 25) + 4],
                Email = stringArray[(i * 25) + 5],
                //Pretend there's more stuff here, I'd rather not show it all
                EstimatedCompletionDate = stringArray[(i * 25) + 23],
                EstimatedCompletionTime = stringArray[(i * 25) + 24]       
            });
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        loadData();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

and the code from class1.cs - the Customer class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Cell { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //Pretend there's more stuff here
    public string EstimatedCompletionDate { get; set; }
    public string EstimatedCompletionTime { get; set; }
}
```

But if I try to get the value from `customers[1].ID` EDIT(from form2.cs), I get "customers does not exist in this current context". How would I declare customers to make it accessible anywhere?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either pass the `customers` object to `Form2` or create a static list.  Either way it needs to be static since `loadData` is static.

To make it static, in your Program.cs you could do something like:

```
public static List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

On the first line of `LoadData` just do:

```
Form1.Customers = new List<Customer>();
```

And then anytime you need to access it, just called `Form1.Customers` (ex: `Form1.Customers[1].ID`)

Comment: As a noob in C#, this answer was easy to follow and understand, and I think it's done exactly what I wanted. I'm now one step closer to C# mastery! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `customers` variable is simply not visible within your `Form2` class. You need to pass `customers` to your instance of `Form2` class (injecting it via custom constructor, a method parameter or by setting a public property / field implemented on the `Form2` class).

You need something like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // add this...
    public List<Customer> Customers
    { 
       get;
       set;
    }
```

And then, if you create `Form2` in your `Program`, what you do is something like:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(); // supposing you have this already, whatever you named it
f2.Customers = customers; // customers being your variable
```

If you're creating your `Form2` from within your `Form1`, then you'd have to pass `customers` to `Form1` first, eg. as `Adam Plocher` showed you (if you make it static), and then further to `Form2`, but the principle remains the same.

On a side note, this is not a very good programming practice, but this is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: How would I make it visible and usable throughout the entire program?

Comment: Bad programming practice? Someone told me in another question this was the best way! Ill see if this works. Will the variables still be editable from any class I pass it to? Because customers(i) will need to be editable at any moment during run time

Answer (score 0):

`loadData()` is `static`, so it can't see non-static instance variables. Change `var customers` to `static var customers`.